# How do the metrics of Google Analytics Site Speed map to the W3C Navigation Timing API?

Tags: performance, google-analytics, navigation-timing-api

The explanations of the site speed metrics provided on [Dimensions & Metrics Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/sitespeed) are unclear (at least to me). They represent events in the [Navigation Timing API](http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/#process) but I cannot figure out which events are the start and end points of each metric.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GA metric names (left) to Navigation Timing labels (right):

```
        pageLoadTime = loadEventStart - navigationStart
    domainLookupTime = domainLookupEnd - domainLookupStart
serverConnectionTime = connectEnd - connectStart
  serverResponseTime = responseStart - requestStart
    pageDownloadTime = responseEnd - responseStart
     redirectionTime = fetchStart - navigationStart
  domInteractiveTime = domInteractive - navigationStart
domContentLoadedTime = domContentLoadedEventStart - navigationStart
```

Comment: pageDownloadTime doesn't look right. Should that be responseEnd - responseStart

Comment: domContentLoadedTime does not look right.  

According to [the official docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=site_speed&jump=ga_domcontentloadedtime) "... parsing of the document is finished, the Document Object Model is ready, but referenced style sheets, images, and subframes may not be finished loading.  

So I would say:  
    **domContentLoadedTime = _domContentLoadedEventEnd_ - navigationStart**

Comment: @igrigorik some of these events (`navigationStart`) are not valid as of today. Appreciate if you could update it :)