# understanding Site Speed Page Timings in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

How to understand Site `Speed Page Timings` in google analytics.

- Is it time that server use to response,
- or it is full time with all DOM elements loadings?

[image: avg. Page Load Time (sec)]

Answer (score 0):

From Google Tooltip: "Avg. Page Load Time is the average amount of time (in seconds) it takes for pages from the sample set to load, from initiation of the pageview (e.g. click on a page link) to load completion in the browser. If you see zero (0) as a value or a small increase in November 2011, read the [About Site Speed article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1205784?topic=1120718&hl=en)."

Take a look at the Technical tab in under the Explorer report:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As stated here ([How do the metrics of Google Analytics Site Speed map to the W3C Navigation Timing API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972615/how-do-the-metrics-of-google-analytics-site-speed-map-to-the-w3c-navigation-timi)), the avg. page load time is:

```
pageLoadTime = loadEventStart - navigationStart
```

loadEventStart and navigationStart are taken from
Navigation Timing API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API